# Read string from TcpClient

Tags: c#, tcp, stream, byte

So I am having trouble reading my string sent through a Tcp stream. I am using this code to send.

```
byte[] bytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("connect");
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.Write(bytes);
writer.Close();
```

And this code to read:

```
public void getConnectionString()
{

    NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
    ns.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    string info = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
    MessageBox.Show(info);
}
```

But all this is returning is System: byte[]

Shouldn't it return the string? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling

```
writer.Write(bytes);
```

which is in turn calling [`TextWriter.Write(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfc2b8zk.aspx) - which simply calls `ToString()` on the `byte[]`. That `ToString()` call will return `System.Byte[]`.

The point of creating a `StreamWriter` is that you can write *text*:

```
writer.Write("connect");
```

So you don't need to call `Encoding.GetBytes()` yourself at all. However, if you *really* want to only send ASCII down the socket, you should specify that explicitly when you create the `StreamWriter`:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII);
```

Of course an alternative is that you don't bother with a `StreamWriter`, and send the bytes directly down the stream. It's important that you understand the difference though: the `Stream` API deals in binary data; the `TextWriter` API deals in text data. (And `StreamWriter` performs that text to binary conversion for you.)